# MX vs SRV records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, srv-record

At first sight, it seems that `MX` and `SRV` records serve the same purpose.

They both:

- Point a client to the name of the host the server is on
- Support prioritizing/fallback

I'm aware that `MX` predates `SRV` (`RFC974` vs `RFC2782`), but in a modern context, `MX` just seems like a specialization of `SRV` for email.

My questions:

- Could MX conceivably be deprecated in favor of `SRV`, retaining all
  functionality?
- If so, is there any initiative in this direction?
- Would there be any advantage to using SRV (besides consistency)?

---

After a bit of investigation, it seems that there *are* [SMTP servers that use `SRV`](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-srv-record-use-by-clients.html#SMTP).

Comment: What is the technical problem you face that needs this question to be answered? Have you read the [help] and ["bad question" list](http://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask)?

Comment: @Sven I guess the motivating practical question is "can I simplify automatic management of my DNS records by using SRV instead of MX" but I already know that I can't, **currently**, so I guess you're right, this is a poor fit for ServerFault. Do you think there's a more appropriate place in StackExchange?

Answer (score 3):

- On a purely theoretical functional/technical level: Yes. In reality: No way. You would have to change an extreme amount of software and *every* MX related DNS entry. Potential gain: Effectively zero.
- No, not that I am aware of. It's useless, so why should there be one?
- `SRV` allows to specify ports. That could be a minor advantage, but since everyone has commited to the ports in use, I don't see why it would be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

1) Conceivably, from a purely technical angle: yes

2) No. The world operates with mx records and there is no incentive to change from a working solution to a different-but-functionally-identical solution.

3) The ability to direct mail for a given domain a non-standard port